# asp.net mvc automapper using

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, automapper

recently i've started to use viewmodels with automapper. 
the problem appeared immediately. for example, i have such classes:

```
public class Zone
{
    public int ZoneId;

    public string Title;

    public int BannersCount;
}

public class ZoneView
{
    public int ZoneId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Title;
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле Кол-во баннеров является обязательным.")]
    [Display(Name = "Кол-во баннеров*")]
    public int BannersCount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and i don't want to edit Title in my view. so there i show Title not in TextEditor but so:

```
@Model.Title
```

and then in my POST action ZoneView comes with empty Title:

```
public ActionResult Edit(ZoneView zoneView)
```

after this i map it to domain model:

```
var zone = zonesRepository.Get(zoneView.ZoneId);
Mapper.Map<ZoneView, Zone>(zoneView, zone);
```

and after this in zone there is empty Title. What is the best way to act in this case?

Comment: Why are you POSTing an empty title?

Comment: @SLaks, because i don't want user to edit Title - only to display it. so it is not placed in TextEditor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a mapping definition, instructing automapper to ignore the Title property when pushing values into Zone.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ZoneView, Zone>()
   .ForMember(destination => destination.Title, member => member.Ignore());
```

You will define this CreateMap once, at application start up. Then map as you have been.

```
var zone = zonesRepository.Get(zoneView.ZoneId);
Mapper.Map<ZoneView, Zone>(zoneView, zone);
```

Comment: +1 I don't know automapper but this sounds like a better solution then mine. cheers

Comment: yes, i create this mapping but without instructions. thank you, i'll try it(=

Comment: Could he also, consider removing the setter from ZoneView.Title as to only accept it through the ZoneView constructor? This way the default model binder wont be able to set the property but he could still display it and that logic becomes a part of the view. Of course the view could not be used elsewhere that allows editing of the Title like in a admin panel though. Just curious what you think?

Comment: He certainly could, but I think that's just jumping through too many hoops unnecessarily. In practice, view models should be very dumb and straight forward, concerned only with specifying the information you want to display or collect, where all the complicated facets of the domain model are flattened or otherwise simplified.

Comment: As I mentioned my thought was he could take it through the constructor but fair enough. To your point I have been using the concept of viewmodels for years now and never put logic business logic in them, was just curious and unfamiliar with using automapper. thanks

Comment: the builder returned by Mapper.CreateMap does have a method called ConstructUsing, which takes the form Func<TSource, TDestination> where he could indeed set it up that way.

Comment: but what about the case if ModelState is not valid - then i return View(zoneView) which has no Title and it will be empty in the view. how can i repair this without mapping again zone to zoneView because then all changes will be lost?

Comment: You could just get the Zone again and set the Title manually. However, you may wish to set the title using ViewData (or ViewBag, if you are using MVC3/.NET 4), which is always populated from the Zone. Since editing the title is not part of your view model, in that case you may wish to omit the Title as part of the model.

Comment: but i thought the main scope of using viewmodels is getting rid of viewbag values. and i understand that i can set the Title manually but i thought there is a best pattern(=

Comment: In this case, your ZoneView is acting as both a view model and a data transfer object (where its responsibility is not only showing what you wish to display, but also collecting values from the user to be saved to a Zone). If you want to work strictly according to those principles, you would probably have 2 view models... oneView and UpdateZoneView, where ZoneView has a Title and UpdateZoneView does not. You'd then change your Edit action to take in an UpdateZoneView instance, and map that to Zone. If validation failed, then you'd retrieve the Zone, map that and then UpdateZoneView to ZoneView

Comment: I don't think there's any harm in using ViewBag for storing stuff for display purposes, and I don't think this situation conflicts with the view model concept. But if you'd like the strict approach I mentioned, go for it :)

Comment: i've solved my problem in such way: i've made TextEditorFor for Title. made it readonly. and because i use your advice and map objects with instructions i'm not afraid of user that can change title with firebug. but also Title is not empty after invalid modelstate(=

Answer (score 0):

- Most of the time i use Hidden input such values.
- And also check at DB level for validation of value with title.

This might not best solution but it works.

Comment: hidden input can be changed by user.